# How to upload audio (3gp) file to firebase storage?

Tags: java, audio, firebase-storage, 3gp

> EDIT: I have added in 'recRef' ".3gp" at the end of the reference and now when I use the emulator it uploads as .3gp file of 0KB and external device still uploads an "application/octet-stream" file (weight 0KB).

I made a record activity to my app and I just cannot upload it properly to firebase storage.
I tried to build an upload process based on the image upload example google published and it uploads an empty file (0KB, type "application/octet-stream").
the recording process is working excellent and I made a play button to check it so I know that it only a problem that I don't know how to upload it properly to the cloud.

You all welcome to use my popup record activity from git: https://github.com/tidharon/Popup-Record-Window-App

Heres my uploading code:

```
recRef = storage.getReference(lastAct + " Records").child(lastTitle);
                metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder().setCustomMetadata(lastID, outputFile).build();


                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] daata = baos.toByteArray();
                uploadTask = (UploadTask) recRef.putBytes(daata, metadata).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        recURL = recRef.toString();
                        getIntent().putExtra("recURL", recURL);
                    }
                });
```

recRef is a StorageReference element.
metadata is a StorageMetadate element.
lastID is the ID of the text document connected to the record.
outputFile is the directory where the record is stored

This is the preparation for the recording process:

```
outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + ("/" + lastAct + " | " + lastID + " | " + date + ".3gp");
    myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try uploading it as a file after the recording complete .putFile(uri_path)

Comment: I tried and it still doesn't upload any file

Answer (score 0):

check what is causing the problem using this

```
.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MyContext, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    })
```

after the closing of  addOnCompleteListener in your code

Comment: It doesn't fail but just don't upload any file to the storage except the name of the file and defying the file as "application/octet-stream".